# clicking on the image in one form open another form with same image

Tags: c#, winforms, image, datagridview

hi   i have two forms form1 and form2 
   i have data grid view in form 1 filling with the data coming from database has two columns product image and product name

i am using winforms with c#

I want to click the one of the column in datagridview(particularly Image column) another form(form2) will be open and in form 2 the image will be displayed in that form

any idea  how to implement this....

many thanks ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the image name or url out of the gridview and pass it to the second form as a parameter. Then in the second form, get the image name you just passed and fill your picturebox (or something else) with the picture you want using the picture name

Comment: sorry i am using winforms and when i click on the image the form2 will be open with that image ...

Comment: he mean to say **path** of the image.

Comment: I tried `ImageLocation` property but does't work but `Image` property worked with me!!!

Comment: if you want the path of the selected image you can try something like

string path = gridview1.selectedRow.Column[0].Value

I'm not sure if it's right I thought of it quickly. You can also store the Image path as a DataKey in the GridView to get it out quickly

Answer (score 1):

`Onclick` event of image of the gridview show the second form then assign `Image` property of its picturebox with the image of gridview

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();
//Here I am not using GridView 
f2.pictureBox1.Image= this.pictureBox1.Image;
```

**Note** you should set the modifier of picture box in second form to public

Answer (score 0):

This is most Suitable way for passing image to another form

**Following Code insert in to Form1**

```
Form2 fm = new Form2(this.picEncode.Image);
fm.Show();
```

**Following Code insert in to Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Image picQr;
    public Form2(Image qrCodeimage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        picQr = qrCodeimage;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = picQr;
    }
}
```